# Меню Bootstrap - Почему при нажатии на кнопку не перебрасывает на другую страницу?

Tags: html, bootstrap, menu

Здравствуйте, меню Bootstrap при клике на любую кнопку переводит пользователя на нужный раздел этой же страницы. Решил я в меню сделать еще одну кнопку "Из Москвы " но прописал ссылку на другую страницу. При нажатии на кнопку перехода на нужную страницу не происходит.
Меню.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Авиабилеты</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/bilety_iz_moskvy/" target="_blank">
Из Москвы</a></li>
           <li><a href="#kurorty">Курорты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tudaobratno">Туда-обратно</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kalendarcen">Календарь цен</a></li>
        <li><a href="#plusy">Плюсы</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не скажу в чем конкретно проблема, но решил при помощи JQuery:

```js
function changePage(event) {
    if($(event.target).hasClass('external')) {
        window.location.href = $(event.target).attr('href');
        return;
    }
}
$(function () {
    $('.nav li').click( changePage );
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Авиабилеты</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/bilety_iz_moskvy/" class="external" target="_blank">
Из Москвы</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#kurorty">Курорты</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tudaobratno">Туда-обратно</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#kalendarcen">Календарь цен</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#plusy">Плюсы</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Почему то один раз срабатывает и все больше не работает